# How to optionally inject a component in angular which does/doesn't exist? (Environment dependent debug bar)

Tags: angular, templates, components, option-type, inject

I want to create a DebugBarComponent which accesses my Mock objects.

This component only exists in my development environment, by exporting different Environment Modules in my environment config (so if I build with --prod it and it's services doesn't exist)

What I need is a concept which enables me without evironment checks, to show the debug in development mode only and do nothing if there is no debug component/service.

`@Optional()` but with components and some kind of template placeholder.

Also I'm unable reference the component in my Template, because it does not always in every environment exist.

So the question basically is:
How to optionally inject a component in angular which does/doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you include examples of how your component is being used.